# Monitoring using telegraf and prometheus

Tags: alert, prometheus, monitoring, telegraf

How can I monitor another server from my pc using prometheus and telegraf? Do I need to install telegraf on both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your question would benefit from more precision including a description of what you've tried (even hypotheses). For this reason, it may get flagged.

Until then...

It appears that Telegraf supports Prometheus as an output plugin ([link](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/prometheus_client)).

So you should be able to:

1. Run Telegraf configured with Prometheus as an output plugin (see above)
2. Run Prometheus configured to scrape the metrics exposed by #1

Assuming you use a Telegraf config of the form:

```
[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
  ## Address to listen on.
  listen = ":9273"
```

You should be able to browse|curl `http://localhost:9273/metrics` from the host on which Telegraf's running to see the metrics it exposes.

> **NOTE** If not `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) then replace `localhost` with the host's name|address.

Then you will want to configure a Prometheus scrape target to scrape the Telegraf metrics:

```
scrape_configs:
  # Telegraf
  - job_name: "telegraf-agent"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9273"
  # Self
  - job_name: "prometheus-server"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9090"
```